# Nested inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I've got question about nested inheritance in C++. I have three classes: `Base`, `Middle` and `Top`. Normally I use public inheritance when deriving from `Middle`, but I have one class (`Top`) which have inherit privately from `Middle`, however it should expose `Base` methods for public usage...

Here's my solution, is it ok?

```
class Base
{
    // ...
}

class Middle :
    public virtual Base
{
    // ...
}

class Top :
    public virtual Base,
    private Middle
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `Base` has a member function `foo`, you can put this in `Top`:

```
public:
    using foo;
```

The same for any other members you need to expose publicly.

Comment: Ok, I know this way, but I want to make whole Base interface public.